# Create element automatically register event handlers to be draggable

Tags: jquery

Say I have some code like this which is called on `$(document).ready():`

```
$(".banana").draggable();

$("body").on("click", "button", function(e){
    $(".banana:first").clone().text('new text').;
});
```

and:

```
<div class="container">
   <button>add</button>
   <div class="banana">banana 1</div>
</div>
```

So,the problem is when I click to create copies of div.banana. It don't automatically register event handler for draggable. I try something but I'm 
sure that's not a good way: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hainguyenduc/fgCZm/7/).

Comment: You can set the jquery framework at jsfiddle at the top-left, so your code actually works.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I know It work. But That's the way I manually add to it. I wonder if anyone know how new element auto register draggable

Comment: @jfriend00 Now you can see it more clearner : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hainguyenduc/fgCZm/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Your new cloned elements are all `position: absolute` so they are all right on top of one another.

If you make your new elements so they aren't `position: absolute` and modify each element so they are different and you can distinguish them from one another, the modified jsFiddle seems to work fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Q8VaT/.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".banana").draggable();

    $(".banana").click(function(e){
        alert("Hello original");
    });

    var cntr = 1;

    $("body").on("click", "button", function(e){
        $(".banana:first").clone().text('new text ' + cntr)
            .data("item", cntr)
            .appendTo(".container").draggable()
            .click(function(e){
                alert("Hello new " + $(this).data("item"));
            });
        ++cntr;
    });

});
```

Comment: $jfriend00. It should not. If there're some event handle bind to '.banana'. Then I have to manually add to it

Comment: That's not what I attend to. Maybe you're not clear. I want that I click to create new element. So, the new element already have able to drag ability as well as click to it, it will alert. You don't need register event handler for it again [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hainguyenduc/N9v3Y/)

Comment: @haind - As I've said earlier, apparently your question is not clear.  My jsFiddle does exactly what you asked for.  It makes a new draggable element that respond to the click.  What more do you want?

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hainguyenduc/N9v3Y/).As I comment.I wonder if I remove comment. What can I do to make new element can be like the first `div.banana`. Auto register event handler means you don't need bind it again.

Comment: @jfrend00 Finally, I solve it [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hainguyenduc/N9v3Y/1/). Anyway, thanks for your help.